# MongoDB Return specified document in Filters

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, document, mongo-java

I have this document [image: Main doc]
It contains this array of document named reviews[image: array of doc reviews]

I tried this code to get the review that were posted by Théo but it keeps returning me the whole document (including sub-documents in reviews) not the one I'm specifing by with Filters.

```
Document document = collection.find(Filters.and(Filters.eq("reviews.reviewer_name", "Théo"))).first();
```

I really can't understand how to get only this specific document. Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes that's a common behavior, it would get the entire array/document if at least one element in array matches with the given filter, In case if you've two fields in filter query then you can use `$elemMatch` or if you've only one field in your filter query you can use `aggregate` & it's stages to get the required output !! It would be better to provide a sample document in text format rather than picture !!

Comment: I’m still new to MongoDB and I don’t find anything in the doc that can help me achieving this (following what you said). Can you give me an idea of the steps?

Comment: Please edit your question - with text format of given document, I can help you with a query !! Also do you think your reviews array has multiple objects where `reviewer_name : Theo` or it would be only one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to do sub-document queries & only retrieve specific sub-documents, there's no way to do that with mongo's simple queries. However, you can use the aggregate pipeline to achieve this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // This is the same as your initial find query, it will limit the top-level docs to only be the ones you are interested in
  { $match: { 'reviewers.reviewer_name': 'Theo' } },

  // You can now unwind the results, which will make all the sub-documents top-level
  { $unwind: '$reviewers' },

  // Re-match to filter the reviewers, this will actually drop the unmatched reviewers
  { $match: { 'reviewers.reviewer_name': 'Theo' } },

  // Now you can use a projection to get the final results you are looking for
  { $project: { reviewer: '$reviewers' } }
])
```

This will return an array of objects with a `reviewer` property, each element containing a single review. You can then use the pagination stages to trim the results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // ... same stages as above, and then:
  { $limit: 1 },
])
```

Not sure what the specific data structures would be with the Java driver you are using, but these are the general mongo queries that will do the trick.

If you want to read more about the aggregate pipeline, I recommend checking out the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) which is so awesome that I have it opened all day. They should have some Java examples on there.

Best of luck!

Comment: you no need to specify $elemMatch on a filter having single field & also $project is not necessarily written that way as we're not renaming/manipulating reviewers. Also this doesn't actually help, as it won't work - since you're just unwinding but not doing anything else, it would just return a bunch of objects from un-wrapped document..!!

Comment: I updated the `$match` to remove `$elemMatch`, thanks for the input. The `$project` is not there for renaming, it is to drop the rest of the document other than the review itself since the `$unwind` keeps the rest of the fields. As for what this returns, the OP has asked for finding a specific `reviewer` document - which this will return.

Comment: I'm saying you no need to do that, a simple thing like this would work : `{ $project: { reviewers: 1 } }`

Comment: Yeah, but I also renamed `reviewers` to `reviewer`, since plural no longer makes sense after an unwind. That's just more of an opinion thing.

Comment: Ok now after edits this seems to be a bit valid query, Still has to be enhanced if O/P needs multiple fields or having multiple matching criteria, but @Jules please keep in mind of using collation on mongoDB if you need something to be searched is not in normal alphabetical format !!